# How do I create aspect point cut for slf4j logger?

Tags: java, log4j, aspectj, slf4j, spring-aop

I want to add strings to all of my logs to achieve this, I am planing to use aop but I couldn't declare point cut for all of my loggger objects. I am using slf4j logger here is an example log in a class

```java
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InterviewService.class);
logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
```

[image]

I am trying to intercept logger in the ss so before printing that log I can alter arguments in message and add my text
I change my code little bit currently I can catch thrown exceptions but still cant intercept logger.error("some error log") messages in aspect method.

```java
@Pointcut("within(org.apache.logging.log4j.*)")
public void logPointcut() {}

@Pointcut("within(*..Log4jLogger.*)")
public void logPointcuts() {}

@Pointcut("execution(* *.error(*))")
public void logPointcutsMethod() {}

@Pointcut("within(*.error)")
public void logPointcutsMethodw() {}

@Around("logPointcutsMethod() || logPointcuts() || logPointcut() || logPointcutsMethodw()")
    public Object logError(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        String user = "";
        if (state)
            user = getUser();
        logger.error(
            "Exception in {} User :{}.{}() with cause = {}", 
            joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
            user,
            joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
        );
        return result;
    }
```

To summarise, I want to create pointcut for every logger.error call so I can add my string to every message

Comment: I would say that it's better to implement using Log4j configuration rather then creating aspect. You can refer https://mkyong.com/logging/log4j2-xml-example/
So, if you need to add some string to every log line you can achieve configuring logger like: 
            <PatternLayout pattern="Your string <rest of the pattern> %msg%n"/>
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

Comment: but my String is not static. it is user name so it will be dynamic object

Comment: I see, then you can have a look into Thread Context.
It's sort of a map of log arguments, once you put some value in the context it will be written on every log line.
So, once you know your username, you put it in context and it should work.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html

Comment: As I Understand from thread context you should set it before logging so if I use this approach then I should add this before every error logging and it is same as changeching every error log.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have web application, so you need to set it only once when request is received, and it will be logged in all the log lines executed from this request.

Comment: Alexander is right, you can use the thread context. But an aspect solution is also possible. Questions: (1) Do you use compile- or load-time weaving? (2) Is it enough to intercept logging calls from your own application, or do you really need to intercept logging calls from somewhere else, e.g. 3rd party libraries not compiled by your own build? (3) I do not see "Unbound pointcut parameter 'callerContext'" locally, so it must come from code you are hiding from, e.g. from somewhere within `formatLogAndProceed`. Can you please edit the question and share that code?

Comment: I really tried thread context but I couldnt achieve that. I couldnt understand your first question, I create a class and add component and aspect annotations and I want to cacht logger.error method calls at run time.2) I just need to catch logger.error calls that is in my application. I dont need to intercept error logs that is not in my application.

Comment: (1) I simply want to know how you apply AspectJ to your code. Are you using the AspectJ compiler? Or are you using the weaving agent `-javaagent:...` to weave aspects? If you have no idea what I am talking about, are you maybe not using native AspectJ at all but something like Spring AOP?

Comment: I am using spring AOP. I also  edit my question. Also you can see my point cut methods from there

Comment: You should have mentioned that, because the code snippet you shared here is obviously meant to be used in native AspectJ. I am assuming you just copied & pasted the code from somewhere out of context. It can never work like this with Spring AOP. Anyway, I am going to write an answer for you, explaining how to solve the problem from within Spring using AspectJ.

Comment: One more question: First you said that you want to add some string to the log message. Now you changed your code, and it looks like you rather want to replace the log message by some standard template. But your current code aslso `proceed` s to the original `error` method, i.e. it would log twice, first the original and then your new message. So what do you really want? You also started to talk about exception handling. So is the aspect only means to log something or to also handle exceptions? Your changed code is just about intercepting `log.error`, before it was about logging in general.

Comment: You really need to learn how to ask a question clearly and also not to completely change the description every time you edit the question. Are you even sure yourself what you want to achieve? It is no problem for me to answer your question from an AOP perspective. What you want is possible. I am just not sure what exactly it is you want.

Comment: Sorry for asking badly. I want to intercept every  log.error that is in my code and edit its arguments before printing error log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249872/discussion-between-cihad-and-kriegaex).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to solve this in native AspectJ, either using load-time weaving or compile-time weaving with the Slf4J and Log4J libraries on the AspectJ compiler's *inpath*. Because Spring AOP can only intercept methods within Spring beans/components, but neither Slf4j nor Log4j are Spring components, you need an AOP framework for adults, not an AOP lite solution like Spring AOP. Fortunately, Spring has a very nice AspectJ integration and also explains it in its [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Application {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    logger.info("Hello Slf4j");
    logger.error("uh-oh", new Exception("oops!"));
    logger.error("WTF dude?!?");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class LogEnhancerAspect {
  @Around("execution(void org.slf4j.Logger.error(String, ..)) && args(msg, ..)")
  public void formatMessageLog(String msg, ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    args[0] = "[MY PREFIX] " + msg;
    joinPoint.proceed(args);
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
0 [main] INFO de.scrum_master.app.Application  - Hello Slf4j
7 [main] ERROR de.scrum_master.app.Application  - [MY PREFIX] uh-oh
java.lang.Exception: oops!
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:13)
8 [main] ERROR de.scrum_master.app.Application  - [MY PREFIX] WTF dude?!?
```

This is the simplest solution. If you need more information in your log output, such as the caller or special information from the exception, it is very easy to adjust the pointcut. Also, `Logger.error(..)` has many overloads. My sample pointcut just catches the ones with the first parameter being a `String`, such as `error(String)` or `error(String, Throwable)`. If you need others, you need to adjust the aspect. But this is basically how it works.

Please also note that this will intercept all error logs, even the ones called from outside your application. If you want to limit it to the base package of your application, you have to adjust the pointcut again and use `call()` rather than `execution()`, something like `within(my.base.pkg..*) && call(void org.slf4j.Logger.error(String, ..)) && args(msg, ..)`.

There are so many ways to tweak this solution, it would take hours to list examples.

Comment: I create new class LogEnhancerAspect  and copy your code but when I run my code and call logger.error it doesnt intercept in your aspect method

Comment: Follow the link to the Spring manual in order to find out how to configure native AspectJ load-time weaving. Like I said before, this is **not** possible with Spring AOP. You really need to read some documentation, too. I cannot do the whole developer job for you, unless you want to hire me. **Copy & paste != programming.** If you want to use a new technology, you need to invest a little bit of time to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it But Above Solution is more proper and fine way to do it

I use ThreadContext in Spring Aop. The below code part is belong to my Spring Aop class, So I create a Pointcut for every endpoint call. when there is an api call it drops into logAround method and I declare ThreadContext in it

```
    @Pointcut("within(com.saas.contoller.*)")
    public void applicationPackagePointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }
    /**
     * Pointcut that matches all Spring beans in the application's main packages.
     */
    @Pointcut("within(com.saas.service.*)")
    public void servicePackagePointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

   @Around("applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String user = "";
        if (state) {
            user = getUser();
        }
        ThreadContext.put("user",user);
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        ThreadContext.remove("user");
```

And also add user prefix to log4j pattern like this

```
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN_CONSOLE" >
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}  - user:%X{user}  %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue, TRACE=cyan}  %style{[%15.15t]}{magenta} : %style{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
```

In this way, before every api call I add username to thread context then log4j uses this user parameter for every logger.error (it depends on how you arrange your log4j.xml file. From this point you could add to trace or info or your custom loglevel) and after api call I must delete this username from thread context because if you dont delete this value from thread context, this thread will go to thread pool and will be called for another process and it will also be carring the value you add in my case it is username. so if I dont delete my value I can see a username where username shouldnt be seen