# Define and increment a prometheus custom counter whenever slf4j Logger error() is being called from my class method's execution(E2E) using AOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, aop, spring-aop

I have a requirement where I want to count number of org.slf4j.Logger.error() calls within my method's execution (across multiple class like controller--service--repo etc). I am thinking to use AOP along with prometheus for this. Below is a sample which I tried,

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DummyController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyController.class);

    @GetMapping("/test-api")
    public void validateTokenDummy() {
        try {
            LOGGER.error("ooppps");     // this is the call for which I want to capture
        } finally {
            System.out.println("inside finally 1");
        }
    }
}
```

AOP code

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ErrorLogCounterAspect {

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    private final Counter errorLogCounter;

    @Autowired
    public ErrorLogCounterAspect(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        System.out.println("inside ErrorLogCounterAspect");
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
        this.errorLogCounter = Counter
                .builder("log.error.calls")
                .description("Testsss")
                .register(meterRegistry);
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(void org.slf4j.Logger.error(..)) && within(com.mypackage.controller.DummyController)")
    public void errorMethodExecution() {
    }


    @After("errorMethodExecution()")
    public void countLogErrorCalls(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        errorLogCounter.increment();
    }
}
```

After deployment, I am getting metrics under /actuator/promethues, but it not getting increemented when I am calling my rest api.

```
# HELP log_error_calls_total Testsss
# TYPE log_error_calls_total counter
log_error_calls_total 0.0
```

Can you please check and tell what mistake am I doing here?

Comment: Spring AOP can only advise Spring container managed bean. SL4J instances here are not spring beans. Do read through  [Spring AOP Capabilities and Goals](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/introduction-spring-defn.html)

Comment: Do go through this SO Q&A : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74571372/4214241 for an AspectJ based solution.

Comment: afaik the logger statistics are already logged by default.

Comment: Hi M.Deinum, they are logged but they get logged from full application point of view. I want to get metrics only for a particular method's full execution point of view. So that I can configure prometheus alert if number of log.errors goes beyond a threshold value in last 30 mins.